# C# CF Post Request | Internal server error 500

Tags: c#, php, post, compact-framework, multipartform-data

I want to keep it as simple as possible -

-We switched from an Godaddy windows hosting to Godaddy linux hosting

-After switching i get internal server error 500 when iam using POST from an c#
 program(compact framework) with the content type - multipartformdata,
 However i can still use a normal html form that sits on the server to post with no issues.

-Everything worked absolutly fine before the switch! I can still do GET requests,
 and even normal(Not multipart/form-data) POST request from my C# app .

Headers and content from the request / response using the code below :

**Request headers -**

```
POST /users/test.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------8d0cb969d25c418
Host: mydomain(i censor)
Content-Length: 403
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Request content -**

```
------------------------------8d0cb969d25c418
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title";

test
------------------------------8d0cb969d25c418
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pwd";

testpwd
------------------------------8d0cb969d25c418
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=test.txt
 Content-Type: text/html

testfile
------------------------------8d0cb969d25c418
```

**Response headers -**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 20 Dec 2013 10:32:01 GMT
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
Content-Length: 662
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

**This is my C# Code(Note - I must use compact framework only) :**

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
NameValueCollection formsdata = new NameValueCollection();
formsdata.Add("title", textBox3.Text);
formsdata.Add("pwd", textBox4.Text);
string[] names = new string[1] { openFileDialog1.FileName };
UploadFilesToRemoteUrl("http://mydomain/users/writefile.php", names,    "notused", formsdata, openFileDialog1.SafeFileName);
```

and for the method UploadFilesToRemoteUrl -

```
        public static void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(string url, string[] files, string
logpath, NameValueCollection nvc, string filename)
        {

            long length = 0;
            string boundary = "----------------------------" +
            DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");


            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" +
            boundary;
            httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = true;
            httpWebRequest2.Credentials =
            System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;



            Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" +
            boundary + "\r\n");


            string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary +
            "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";

            foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
            {
                string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
                byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
            }


            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

            string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=" + filename + "\r\n Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {

                //string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file" + i, files[i]);
                string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file", files[i]);

                byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

                memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);


                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(files[i], FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                }


                memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);


                fileStream.Close();
            }

            httpWebRequest2.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

            Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream();

            memStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
            memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            memStream.Close();
            requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            requestStream.Close();


            WebResponse webResponse2 = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();

            Stream stream2 = webResponse2.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);


            MessageBox.Show(reader2.ReadToEnd());

            webResponse2.Close();
            httpWebRequest2 = null;
            webResponse2 = null;
        }
```

**Any help is really highly appreciated!**

Comment: If the PHP scripts are failing you'll need to do the debugging on the server side, the chances are that there's not enough information being sent to the client side for any meaningful debugging.  If you moved from Windows to Linux then a couple of obvious points are that Linux is case-sensitive so a file include may be failing that used to work on the case-insensitive Windows, the extensions you were using may no longer be available, the PHP versions may be different, etc.

Comment: Hi, it looks like im not even reaching my php script, the request and response headers are staying the same no matter where i am posting to.(even if iam posting to blank php file)